# Should change this and start using exceptions?

Tags: php, exception

I understood the concept of Exceptions, but I still can't undestand why I should replace the way I do error handling to the Exception way.
Here's a simple code that serves as an example of how I do things without exception:

```
validate_form_data($data, &$errors=array())
{
    //expects $_POST to be passed as argument ($data)

    $errors = array();

    if(strlen($data['name']) < 3)
        $errors[] = "Your name must contain at least 3 characters.";

    if($data['age'] > 200)
        $errors[] = "You can't be older than 200."

    if(count($errors))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

///submit_form.php

$errors = array();

if(validate_form_data($_POST, $errors))
{
    // do something like sending data to MySQL and output sucess message.
}
else
{
    //loop thru the $errors array and display its values so the user knows what mistakes he made
}
```

My question is: Will using exceptions make my life easier, if so, how?

Comment: Where in the code you are thinking about using exceptions? That a user inputs an invalid name is not an exception, but it's something you must expect.

Comment: My feeling is exceptions are useful when trying to capture an execution's failure, with the intent of "handling" that failure gracefully. It's ultimately a technique, though, and I'm with @KingCrunch; your example is more akin to validation, not a function with a broken training wheel.

Answer (score 4):

Exceptions, as their name suggests, should be thrown in exceptional cases in your application. But, since what you're doing is validating data, havinng to deal with invalid data isn't an exceptional case: it's a condition you're expecting. So, using exceptions in that script won't make your life easier, and it isn't even correct.

The only thing I would change is the way you return the errors:

```
function validate_form_data($data)
{
    $errors = array();

    if (strlen($data['name']) < 3) {
        $errors[] = "Your name must contain at least 3 characters.";
    }

    if ($data['age'] > 200) {
        $errors[] = "You can't be older than 200.";
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: Not really. `$errors` captures valuable information that could be displayed to the user on the form. It seems odd to collect it only to throw it out at the end. You may as well keep a boolean the whole way through.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I also wanted to propose my version of the validation function. :)

Comment: I think it simplifies the actual function, but now the actual determination if the data that is validated is "valid" is passed off to the calling script, ie, a `count($validation_result)` or otherwise is required. If the error values are superfluous, returning a boolean in addition to allowing for contextualization of the error is a suitable approach IMO.

Comment: It depends on the application. I think telling the user what needs to be fixed is invaluable. Others may be content with "You entered bad data. Too bad!" :P

Comment: Yes, but he's also retrieving the errors in the function, so they're obviously displayed somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that exceptions imply unexpected problems. For one thing, your code is specifically checking for the problem so it's definitely expected. From the definition of *exception*,

> anything excluded from or not in conformance with a general rule, principle, class, etc.

they are known cases that must be excluded but accounted for. They are designed for situations that require leaving the normal flow of execution and make it easier to handle the problem non-locally.

If the method that detects the error isn't going to handle it, i.e. decide what course of action to take, it can throw an exception so that the caller can either handle it or let it propagate to their caller, and so on. You can do this by returning an error code, but that forces every caller in the execution stack to check for and return an error code. PHP automatically rethrows exceptions to the caller if a method doesn't catch them.

Since the purpose of the method above is to check user input for validity, it makes more sense to return the result of that check: yes or no. Also, you're probably going to use that result in the code that calls the method so there's no need to let the exception bubble up the stack.